# Importing environment variables settings from another server

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables

I would like to import all the 'env' variables from another box to a local machine. I have copied the env variables into env_var.txt on the local box. I have performed the following:

```
for i in `cat env_var.txt`; do export $i; done
```

However, this doesn't seem to set all my env variables correctly. I have modified

```
do export $i
```

into

```
do echo $i
```

and the variables seem to display all fine. What could be causing this problem. Or is there an alternative way to import all the env variables?

Comment: Why not just `$(cat env_var.txt)`?

Comment: Wow that worked...That's much simpler too. Thanks!

Comment: Anytime; glad to have helped.

Comment: How did you create `env_var.txt`? If you just did `env > env_var.txt`, then, in general, it's impossible.

Comment: Hey Scott, yes I just did 
    env>env_var.txt
I used DopeGhoti's recommendation and it imported the variables just fine

Comment: @DopeGhoti That only works if there are no special characters in the values.

Answer (score 3):

TL,DR: export with

```
export -p >env_var.sh
```

and import with

```
. env_var.sh
```

---

Whether your code works depends on the format of `env_var.txt` and what special characters (i.e. characters that have a special meaning in shell syntax) are present in the variables' names and values.

`` `cat env_var.txt` `` is an unquoted command substitution. Leaving a variable command substitution unquoted applies the “split+glob” operator to it: first split the output of the command at the characters in the value of the `IFS` variable, then interpret each piece as a file name wildcard pattern and replace each pattern that matches some files by the names of the matching files. The result is a list of words that the `for` loop iterates on.

An unquoted command substitution is rarely what you want, and in this case it's definitely not what you want. It does work, however, if the syntax of the file is e.g. the output of `env` *and the values of the variables don't contain any of `*?\[` or whitespace*.

If `env_var.txt` is the output of `env`, you can get better results if you parse it according to its actual syntax (newline-separated assignments), rather than using a parsing method that doesn't make sense. If you want to use the split+glob operator, which is the easiest way to do this, set `IFS` to be a newline only, and turn of wildcard matching.

```
set -f; IFS='
'
export `cat env_var.txt`
set +f; unset IFS
```

There is a problem that you can't solve on the recipient side however, which is that the output of `env` is ambiguous. Given the following content:

```
foo=bar
hello=world
```

there's no way to tell whether there are two variables (one called `foo` with the value `bar` and one called `hello` with the value `world`) or just one that's called `foo` with the value

```
bar
hello=world
```

To export the environment variables in an unambiguous way, **don't use `env`, use `export` instead**. The command `export -p` lists the values of all environment variables in a way that can be parsed back by the shell. So on the export side, run

```
export -p >env_var.sh
```

On the import side, run

```
. env_var.sh
```

Caveat: in bash, the output of `export -p` is parseable, but only by bash. To get output that works in other sh-style shells, set `POSIXLY_CORRECT` to any value value. This has no harmful effect in other shells, so you can just do

```
(POSIXLY_CORRECT=$POSIXLY_CORRECT; export -p) >env_var.sh
```

Setting `POSIXLY_CORRECT` to the value that it had before doesn't make a difference to the output — either it wasn't in the environment and it won't be after running this, or it was in the environment and its value doesn't change. But it's enough to force bash to use the portable syntax with `export` in the output of `export -p` rather than a bash-specific syntax with `declare`.

Note that importing environment variables can lead to the execution of arbitrary code, so make sure that you only import `env_var.txt` or `env_var.sh` from a source that you trust. The culprit is the environment variables, not the fact that `. env_var.sh` executes the code: just importing variables such as `PATH`, `LD_PRELOAD`, `ENV`, etc. can lead to code execution further down the line.

Answer (score 1):

Use the bash "source" command in that way:

```
source env_var.txt
```

All variables should be imported.

For more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_(command)

Comment: Whether this works depends on how the variables were exported.

Comment: This works but I think this is only for that session. Sourcing allows one to use the env variables for that instance but won't be available the next login. I followed DopeGhoti's example of $(cat env_var.txt)